# Apache Solr : Filter results by minimum relevancy in drupal 6.x

Tags: drupal-6

We need to filter results by minimum relevancy, i tried to modify query in hook "hook_apachesolr_query_alter()" following way and failed, can someone help me

1) Add filter score:[0.5 TO *] with exclude as false - It display no items

2) Add filter score:[0.5 TO *] with exclude as true - There is no change in result, it display all items

3) Add parameter q = {!frange l=5}query($qq) and qq = <actual_query> - Getting 400 error

4) Add {!frange l=5}query($qq) and qq =  in sortstring
- There is no change in result, it display all items